# PHP update is not updating database with checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

to all i have a weird problem when i am trying to update a table of my database with checkboxes  it takes only one value and  all the rest just ingnores them here is my php code so far

```
foreach ($_POST['choice'] as $id){
    $price=$_POST['price'][$id];
    $availability=$_POST['availability'][$id];

    $result1=mysql_query("UPDATE store SET storeid='".$id."',availability='".$availability."', price='".$price."'  WHERE productid='".$par1."'");
}
```

Yes you are right and i am deeply sorry for the lack of information.Here is my html code as well

```
echo "<td><input type='text' id='availability[".$row->id ."]' name='availability[".$row->id ."]'  value='".$row->diathesimotita ."' size='20'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' id='price[".$row->id ."]' name='price[".$row->id ."]'  value='".$row->price ."'  size='10'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='choice[".$row->id ."]' name='choice[".$row->id ."]'  value='".$row->id ."'   /></td>";
echo"</tr>";
```

So i am trying to take the textbox values which are in the same row with the check box but it gets only the first checked ckeckbox

Comment: what is your html, no way of finding issues without the complete code..

Comment: `$par1` does not change in the loop.

Comment: Try typing `<pre><?php echo print_r($_POST); ?></pre>`. This will print out the $_POST fields so you can then work out how to get the data. I think the $_POST will have multiple variables called `availability` etc

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection. When writing new code, you should consider using PDO or mysqli. >[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: If you have an array of `price[]` values, then you probably want to use `foreach ($_POST['choice'] as $key=>$id)`, so you can pass the array `$key` to the other arrays. Although without more information on what you're trying to accomplish, this is hard to answer.

Comment: yes i am sorry, i edited my initial post,thanks for your quick reply

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes only post a value when they are checked. You should validate them or set a value first before trying to use them in a query (for security if nothing else!). For example do this at the top of your processing code:

```
$checkbox_val = (!empty($_POST['choice']) ? 'Yes' : 'No');  //example only assuming non-array for 'choice'
```

This will set the value to 'No' if the POST value is empty or not set, guaranteeing that you always have a value. You can change the values to 0/1, true/false, etc.

Also, without seeing what is in your 3 $_POST arrays, it is impossible for us to tell you if you are getting the correct values for `$price` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code looks fine; we need to see the HTML code, but anyway try this in SQL:

```
UPDATE store SET storeid='".$id."' , availability='".$availability."' , price='".$price."'     WHERE productid='".$par1."'" );
```

Spaces really matter in SQL. If this does not work please show us the HTML code.